# How can i possible fit this table into Latex? It's my first time using LateX

Tags: tables, article, size, msword

I just stared using Latex and i have to make the following table into a latex version : [image: The table that i need to use]

This table occupies 9 pages in Word format and has alot of text. (It has 3 topics on the rotated label: Sensor, Algoritmos, Implantes.
I've used the following code:

```
\documentclass[fleqn,10pt]{SelfArx} % Document font size and equations flushed left
\usepackage[english]{babel} % Specify a different language here - english by default
\usepackage{url} % Required to insert dummy text. To be removed otherwise
\usepackage{balance}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{mathptmx}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{times}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{gensymb} % degree. ie 360º
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{comment}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage[framemethod=tikz]{mdframed}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[labelfont=bf]{subcaption}
\usepackage[section]{placeins}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage[hmargin=3cm]{geometry}   
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{threeparttable}



\usepackage{tcolorbox}% http://ctan.org/pkg/tcolorbox
\definecolor{mycolor}{rgb}{0,0,0}% Rule colour
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\mybox}[1]{%
    \setbox0=\hbox{#1}%
    \setlength{\@tempdima}{\dimexpr\wd0+13pt}%
    \begin{tcolorbox}[colframe=mycolor,boxrule=0.5pt,arc=4pt,
        left=6pt,right=6pt,top=6pt,bottom=6pt,boxsep=0pt,width=\@tempdima]
        #1
    \end{tcolorbox}
}
\makeatother
\usepackage[resetlabels,labeled]{multibib}
\newcites{A}{Appendix}
\usepackage[num]{abntex2cite}
\citebrackets[]
\begin{document}
\begin{table*}[H!]
       \begin{center}
      \caption{Resumo de vários estudos e os seus resultados}
    \begingroup
     \footnotesize 
      \centering 
        \begin{longtable}{|c|c|p{20.5em}|{10.5em}|}
          \hline
             \makecell{Abordagem} & \makecell{Artigo}  & \makecell{Resultados}\\
            \hline
            \endhead
            Sensor & Onorati et al.\cite{Onorati2021} & Sensibilidade: 92\% pacientes pediátricos , 94\% pacientes adultos. Taxa de alarmes falsos é maior em pacientes pediátricos do que em pacientes adultos, durante sono a taxa reduziu para 0 em todos os pacientes.\\
               \hline
             & Meisel et al.\cite{Meisel2020} & Melhoria em relação à chance média: 28.5\%, Performance de predição positiva: 43.5\% dos pacientes. Em todos os pacientes observados, a melhoria em relação média :14.1\%, Sensibilidade: 51.2\%. \\
               \hline
            & Tang et al.\cite{Tang2021} &  Algoritmo ‘machine learning’ 1: Deteção de 8 em 9 tipos diferentes de crises epilépticas. Algoritmo ‘machine learning’ 2: Deteção de 9 em 9 tipos diferentes de crises epilépticas.\\
           
             \hline
         
            Algoritmo & Runarsson et al.\cite{Runarsson}] & Precisão:  90\% \\
               \hline
            & Wang et al.\cite{Wang2021} & Precisão: 77.6\%. Sensibilidade: 82,7\%. Especificidade: 72.4\%.\\
               \hline
             & Daoud et al.\cite{Daoud2019} & Modelo MLP: Sensibilidade: 84.67\%, Precisão: 83.63\%. Modelo DCNN + MLP: Sensibilidade: 95.41\%,Precisão: 92.80\%. Modelo DCCN + BiLSTM: Sensibilidade: 99.72\%,  Precisão: 99.60\%. Modelo DCAE + BiLSTM:  Sensibilidade: 99.72\%, Precisão: 99.66\%.\\
               \hline
             & Beniczky et al.\cite{Beniczky2021} & Taxa de concordância: 87.2\%.\\
             
             \hline
             
            Implante & Serdaroglu et al.\cite{Serdaroglu2016} & Redução de frequência de crises epiléticas igual ou superior a 50\%:
            9.8\% em 6 meses,
            24\% em 2 anos,
            46.4\% em 3 anos
            E 54\% em 5 anos.\\
               \hline
             & Ardesch et al.\cite{Ardesch2007} & Redução média de crises epilépticas: 14\% no primeiro ano, 50\% no sexto ano. Redução de frequência de crises epilépticas em 5 anos: 50\%.\\
               \hline
             & Tzadok et al.\cite{Tzadok2019} & Redução de frequência média de crises epiléticas igual ou superior a 50\%: 
            60.9\%.\\
               \hline
             & Toffa et al.\cite{Toffa2020} & Redução de frequência de crises epiléticas igual ou acima de 50\%:
            45\% a 65\% dos pacientes epiléticos em 6 meses.\\
               \hline
             & Shahwan et al.\cite{Shahwan2009} & Redução de frequência de crises epiléticas igual ou acima de 50\%:
            54\% dos pacientes.\\
              \hline
             & Orosz et al. \cite{Orosz2014} & Redução de frequência de crises epiléticas igual ou acima de 50\%:
            32.5\% em 6 meses,
            37.7\% em 12 meses,
            43.8\% em 24 meses.\\
               \hline
             & Cohen-Gadol et al \cite{Cohen-Gadol2003} & Redução de frequência de crises epiléticas em 2 estudos aleatórios:
            30\% em 3 meses.
            Em estudos a longo termo:
            35\% dos pacientes atingem uma redução igual ou superior a 50\% e 20\% dos pacientes atingem uma redução de 75\% em 18 meses.\\
               \hline
             & Skarpaas T. et al\cite{Skarpaas2019} & Redução de frequência mediana de crises epilépticas: 75\% em 9 anos.\\
               \hline
             & Kokoszka et al.\cite{Kokoszka2018} & Primeira criança: redução para 3 crises epilépticas por dia e de gravidade de crise. Com estimulação corticotalâmica, foi reduzido mais 50\% de frequência de crises epilépticas. Segunda criança: Redução de crises para 2 por mês no décimo sétimo mês.\\
               \hline
             & Razavi et al.\cite{Razavi2020} & Redução de frequência mediana de crises epilépticas: 67\% no primeiro ano, 75\% no segundo ano, 82\% no terceiro ou mais.\\
               \hline
             & Nair et al.\cite{Nair2019} & Redução de frequência mediana de crises epilépticas: 75\%  no nono ano.\\
              \hline
             & Geller et al.\cite{Geller2017} & Redução de frequência mediana de crises epiléticas:
            70\%.\\
               \hline
             & Heck et al.\cite{Heck2014} & Redução de frequência mediana de crises epiléticas:
            44\% em 1 ano, 53\% em 2 anos.\\
               \hline
             & Li et al.\cite{Li2018} & Estimulação do núcleo anterior de tálamo:Redução de 46\%-90\%. Estimulação do Hipocampus: Redução de 48\%-95\%.\\
               \hline
             & Salanova et al.\cite{Salanova2021} & Redução mediana de frequência de crises epiléticas:
            75\% em 7 anos.
            Redução mediana de frequência de crises focais para bilaterais tónico-clónicas:
            71\% em 7 anos.\\
               \hline
             & Järvenpää et al.\cite{Soila2020} & Redução média de frequência de crises focais sem consciência:
            56\% em 2 anos, 
            65\% em 5 anos.
            No tipo de crises focais com consciência e crises focais para bilaterais tónico-clónicas, as alterações foram menos destacadas.\\
              \hline
             & Herrman et al.\cite{Herrman2018} & Redução de frequência  de crises epilépticas: 22\%. 4 pacientes atingiram uma redução maior que 50\% e 5 pacientes com uma redução maior que 50\% em crises focais.\\
                \hline 
          \end{longtable}
         \endgroup
    \end{center}
    \end{table*}
\end{document}
```

I've tried to shorten the table to 3 collums but im not allowed to do such and i need to follow exactly the word version in latex.
I've tried longtables, tabularx and other code i found in the documention but to no avail.
Either it doesnt go to the other page, or the text overlaps or just doesnt appear at all.
Im using a template already made with the following document SelfArx:

```
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Stylish Article
% Class File
% Version 2.1 (1/10/15)
%
% This template has been downloaded from:
% http://www.LaTeXTemplates.com
%
% Original author:
% Mathias Legrand (legrand.mathias@gmail.com)
% With extensive modifications by:
% Vel (vel@latextemplates.com)
%
% License:
% CC BY-NC-SA 3.0 (http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-nc-sa/3.0/)
%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesClass{SelfArx}[25/01/2012, v1.0]
\RequirePackage{ifthen}
\RequirePackage{calc}
\AtEndOfClass{\RequirePackage{microtype}}
\DeclareOption*{\PassOptionsToClass{\CurrentOption}{article}}
\ProcessOptions*
\LoadClass{article}
\RequirePackage{ifpdf}      % Needed to pick between latex and pdflatex

%----------------------------------------------------------------------
%   FONTS
%----------------------------------------------------------------------

\RequirePackage{times}      % Loads the Times-Roman Fonts
\RequirePackage{mathptmx}   % Loads the Times-Roman Math Fonts

%----------------------------------------------------------------------
%   VARIOUS USEFUL PACKAGES
%----------------------------------------------------------------------

\RequirePackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\RequirePackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb}
\RequirePackage{graphicx,xcolor}
\RequirePackage{booktabs}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------
%   MARGINS 
%----------------------------------------------------------------------
          
\RequirePackage[left=2cm,%
right=2cm,%
top=2.25cm,%
bottom=2.25cm,%
headheight=11pt,%
letterpaper]{geometry}%
                
%----------------------------------------------------------------------
%   FIGURES AND TABLES CAPTIONS
%----------------------------------------------------------------------

\RequirePackage[labelfont={bf,sf,small},%
labelsep=period,%
justification=raggedright]{caption}
\setlength{\abovecaptionskip}{0pt}
\setlength{\belowcaptionskip}{0pt}
                
%----------------------------------------------------------------------
%   PAGE HEADER
%----------------------------------------------------------------------

\RequirePackage{fancyhdr}  % Needed to define custom headers/footers
\RequirePackage{lastpage}  % Number of pages in the document
\pagestyle{fancy}          % Enables the custom headers/footers
% Headers
\lhead{}%
\chead{}%
\rhead{\@ShortTitle}
% Footers
\lfoot{}%
\cfoot{}%
\rfoot{\color{gray}\small\sffamily\bfseries R.~Inform.~Teór.~Apl.~(Online)~$\bullet$~Porto Alegre~$\bullet$~V.~\@PaperVol~$\bullet$~N.~\@PaperNum~$\bullet$~p.\thepage/\pageref{LastPage}~$\bullet$~\@PaperAno}%
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}% % No header rule
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}% % No footer rule

%----------------------------------------------------------------------
%   SECTION/SUBSECTION/PARAGRAPH SET-UP
%----------------------------------------------------------------------

\RequirePackage[explicit]{titlesec}
\titleformat{\section}
  {\color{color1}\large\sffamily\bfseries}
  {}
  {0em}
  {\colorbox{white}{\parbox{\dimexpr\linewidth-2\fboxsep\relax}{\arabic{section}. #1}}}
  []
\titleformat{name=\section,numberless}
  {\color{color1}\large\sffamily\bfseries}
  {}
  {0em}
  {\colorbox{white}{\parbox{\dimexpr\linewidth-2\fboxsep\relax}{#1}}}
  []  
\titleformat{\subsection}
  {\color{color1}\sffamily\bfseries}
  {\thesubsection}
  {0.5em}
  {#1}
  []
\titleformat{\subsubsection}
  {\sffamily\small\bfseries}
  {\thesubsubsection}
  {0.5em}
  {#1}
  []    
\titleformat{\paragraph}[runin]
  {\sffamily\small\bfseries}
  {}
  {0em}
  {#1} 
\titlespacing*{\section}{0pc}{3ex \@plus4pt \@minus3pt}{5pt}
\titlespacing*{\subsection}{0pc}{2.5ex \@plus3pt \@minus2pt}{0pt}
\titlespacing*{\subsubsection}{0pc}{2ex \@plus2.5pt \@minus1.5pt}{0pt}
\titlespacing*{\paragraph}{0pc}{1.5ex \@plus2pt \@minus1pt}{10pt}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------
%   TABLEOFCONTENTS SET-UP
%----------------------------------------------------------------------
\newlength{\tocsep} 
\setlength\tocsep{1.5pc} % Sets the indentation of the sections in the table of contents
\setcounter{tocdepth}{3} % Three levels in the table of contents section: sections, subsections and subsubsections

\usepackage{titletoc}
\contentsmargin{0cm}
\titlecontents{section}[\tocsep]
  {\addvspace{4pt}\small\bfseries\sffamily}
  {\contentslabel[\thecontentslabel]{\tocsep}}
  {}
  {\hfill\thecontentspage}
  []
\titlecontents{subsection}[\tocsep]
  {\addvspace{2pt}\sffamily}
  {\contentslabel[\thecontentslabel]{\tocsep}}
  {}
  {\ \titlerule*[.5pc]{.}\ \thecontentspage}
  []
\titlecontents*{subsubsection}[\tocsep]
  {\footnotesize\sffamily}
  {}
  {}
  {}
  [\ \textbullet\ ]  

%----------------------------------------------------------------------
%   MULTIPLE AUTHOR SET
%----------------------------------------------------------------------  
  
\newcount\@authcnt
\newcount\@tmpcnt\@tmpcnt\z@

\def\@affiliation{%
  \ifnum\@tmpcnt<\@authcnt
   \global\advance\@tmpcnt1
    \raggedright \csname @auth\romannumeral\the\@tmpcnt\endcsname\hfill\\%
   \let\next\@affiliation \vskip1pt
  \else
   \let\next\relax
  \fi
\next}
     
\newcommand{\affiliation}[1]{%
    \global\advance\@authcnt1
    \expandafter\gdef\csname @auth\romannumeral\the\@authcnt\endcsname
    {#1}}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------
%   LIST CONTROL
%----------------------------------------------------------------------  

\RequirePackage{enumitem}
%\setlist{nolistsep} % Uncomment to remove spacing between items in lists (enumerate, itemize)

%----------------------------------------------------------------------
%   ABSTRACT+AUTHOR FRAME
%----------------------------------------------------------------------  

\newcommand{\PaperTitle}[1]{\def\@PaperTitle{#1}}
\newcommand{\ShortTitle}[1]{\def\@ShortTitle{#1}}
\newcommand{\Titulo}[1]{\def\@Titulo{#1}}
\newcommand{\PaperVol}[1]{\def\@PaperVol{#1}}
\newcommand{\PaperAno}[1]{\def\@PaperAno{#1}}
\newcommand{\PaperNum}[1]{\def\@PaperNum{#1}}
\newcommand{\Archive}[1]{\def\@Archive{#1}}
\newcommand{\Authors}[1]{\def\@Authors{#1}}
\newcommand{\JournalInfo}[1]{\def\@JournalInfo{#1}}
\newcommand{\Abstract}[1]{\def\@Abstract{#1}}
\newcommand{\Resumo}[1]{\def\@Resumo{#1}}
\newcommand{\Keywords}[1]{\def\@Keywords{#1}}
\newcommand{\PalavrasChave}[1]{\def\@PalavrasChave{#1}}
\newcommand{\Doi}[1]{\def\@Doi{#1}}
\newcommand{\DateR}[1]{\def\@DateR{#1}}
\newcommand{\DateA}[1]{\def\@DateA{#1}}
% ---------------------------------------------------------------------

\renewcommand{\@maketitle}{%
\twocolumn[{%
\thispagestyle{empty}%
\vskip-36pt%
{\raggedleft\small\sffamily\bfseries\@JournalInfo\\\@Archive\par}%
\vskip18pt%
{\raggedright\color{color1}\sffamily\bfseries\fontsize{18}{19}\selectfont \@PaperTitle\par}%
\vskip10pt%
{\raggedright\color{gray}\sffamily\bfseries\fontsize{12}{14}\selectfont \@Titulo\par}%
\vskip10pt%
{\raggedright\color{color1}\sffamily\fontsize{12}{16}\selectfont  \@Authors\par}%
\vskip18pt%
\fcolorbox{color1}{white}{%
\parbox{\textwidth-2\fboxsep-2\fboxrule}{\centering%
\colorbox{color2!10}{%
\parbox{\textwidth-4\fboxsep-2\fboxrule}{%
\ifx\@Keywords\@empty%
\sffamily\textbf{\abstractname}\\\@Abstract\\%
\else%
\sffamily\textbf{\abstractname :}~\@Abstract\\
\textbf{\keywordname :}~\@Keywords\\%

\sffamily\textbf{Resumo:~\Resumo}\@Resumo\\%
\textbf{Palavras-Chave:}~\@PalavrasChave%

\fi%
}%
}%
\vskip4pt%
\begingroup%
\raggedright\sffamily\small%
\footnotesize\@affiliation\par%
\sffamily\textbf{DOI:~}\@Doi~~~$\bullet$~~~\textbf{Received:~}\@DateR~~~$\bullet$~~~\textbf{Accepted:~}\@DateA\\\textit{CC BY-NC-ND 4.0 - This work is licensed under a Creative Commons Attribution-NonCommercial-NoDerivatives 4.0 International License.}
\endgroup%%
}%
}%
\vskip25pt%
}]%
}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------
%   REFERENCES
%----------------------------------------------------------------------  

% Remove brackets from numbering in List of References
\renewcommand{\@biblabel}[1]{\bfseries\color{color1}\textsuperscript{[#1]}}
%\setlength{\bibitemsep}{0cm}
\let\oldbibliography\thebibliography
\renewcommand{\thebibliography}[1]{%
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\refname}%
\oldbibliography{#1}%
\setlength\itemsep{0pt}}%
```

Can someone give me some tips on how to fit this enourmous table in Latex?

Comment: See the Use Long Tables section in the `tabularray` package. Also you need to provide a minimal working example that compiles all by itself.

Comment: Sorry, how do i do that? Im really new to these things.

Comment: The MWE should start with `\documentclass` and include `begin{document}` and `\end{document}`.

Comment: Ah, i hope i managed to do that now. Thanks.

Comment: The MWE doesn't compile for me. I don't have the `SelfArx` document class. EDIT: Looks like you are using this: https://github.com/Opware2000/Latex_templates/blob/master/Stylish%20Article/SelfArx.cls

Comment: I belive so, but i edited the post so that it has the SelfArx code.

Comment: Welcome. // I suggest to start a separate tex file, base it on article and copy your table code there: there simply may be unwanted interactions from all those packages etc. May be it‘s good to EDIT your question and add this simplified code, too. // Did you have a look here? https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Tables

Comment: Sorry i cant put the simplified code atm, as soon as i can, ill edit it. I did, but everytime i tried to implement said code, it would go over the page limits or not appear at all.